# Incorrect bundle identifier for Expo App when uploading .ipa to the App Store with Transporter.app

Tags: ios, expo, app-store, iosdeployment

After building an Expo application archive via `expo build:ios`, uploading the `.ipa` file via Transporter.app fails with this error:

> **Could not create a temporary .itmsp package for the app "filename.ipa"**
>
>  No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier "___" is correct.

The bundle identifier shown in the error message has been quadruple checked and is correct and matches the bundle identifier created by Expo in the Apple developer portal.

As the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/uploading-apps) suggests I have logged into iTunes connect and accepted the terms, I'm logged in Transporter (I've restarted both this app and the computer a couple of times) but I always get this error.

Any ideas?

On this [link](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pingpongbuds.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202021-01-09%20at%2013.11.29.png?alt=media&token=b0348c09-4be5-459e-92cb-9a6d40e8264f) there is a screenshot.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you create the app at https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps already?

Comment: yes everything seems to be ok but it still doesn't work!

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Expo SDK 40, Expo CLI v4.x.x.  It looks like everything is all setup the way it normally is in the Developer console, except uploading fails in exact same way described.

Comment: I contacted apple and they said I should try through Xcode. Haven't tried yet though!

Comment: Thanks @D.Mika, this is what unlocked this for me.  That step is either poorly documented or missing from Expo.

Answer (score 6):

This was resolved for me when I created an app at [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps), which is separate from the steps to create certificates and provisioning profiles in the Apple Developer Portal.

Once I created a new App there and mapped it to the bundle identifier I created in the Apple Developer Portal, I was able to upload the binary.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm Pat's answer

When you do `expo build:ios` you will be given an ipa that you can download from the expo dashboard.

When you try to transport that to app store connect for the first time it will fail with the error the questioner has posted.

You need to go to app store connect, click add an app and from the dropdown select your bundle identifier it should be prepopulated.

Next go back to transporter and drag your ipa and click deliver.